# CSS: Make image padding not affect shadow

Tags: html, css

So, i have simple css but big problem...

```
.separator a img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

And the result is: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ySs2.png)

As you can see on the image, shadow is showing on padding of the image but i want it to show on the image.

I want to do [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALSqY.png) but also to keep the padding.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: **margin** is *outside* the element, **padding** is *inside* the element.

Comment: Do not use the property padding in an image, that's nonsense. Instead use it in your anchor element, like in this [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/35ffmszx/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`margin` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin). Padding goes on the inside of the border-box, whereas margin goes outside.

Since the shadow is (I'm assuming) applied via `box-shadow`, the margin will be outside of it and the shadow will display directly adjacent to the image.

Try changing `padding: 12px` to `margin: 12px`.

Comment: I've tried with margin and shadow is on image, but image goes over the text.

Comment: @KibiBrat That's unexpected, it sounds like other styles on the page are interfering. It would be helpful if you posted a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question, so we can investigate the problem further.

Comment: Yeah, i checked it yesterday and it was mistake in other style....Anyway, thank you very much for answering, i'm sure this will help someone else someday...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `margin` instead of `padding`. Think of `padding` as being 'inside' the box, and `margin` as being the space between the box and other things on the page.

Comment: Don't copy @rvighne :)

Comment: This is a comment. not a answer.

Comment: @KibiBrat I didn't copy, we just both answered within the same minute.

Comment: @sara how Is this not an answer? Is it simply because of the fact that I used the phrase 'try using margin ...' instead of 'use margin ...'?

Comment: @sara An answer does not have to have code. This is a valid answer.

Comment: @sara isn't that rather pedantic for an issue like this? My solution is an answer, by any stretch of the English language.